# Django. ForeignKey object does not get updated/changed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a button in my template to change/update ForeignKey object in the database.

However, the object that should be updated is not changed.

How can I update the ForeignKey object in the database?

```
Views.py 

   if 'order' in request.POST:
    status_change = request.POST['order']
    order = Order.objects.get(pk = status_change)

    if order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS == 'Received':
        order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS='Requested'
        order.save()
    elif order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS == 'Requested':
        order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS = 'Completed'
        order.save()
    elif order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS == 'Completed':
        order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS = 'Canceled'
        order.save()
    else:
        order.orderstatus.ORDERSTATUS = 'Received'
        order.save()

Models.py

RECEIVED = 'Received'
REQUESTED = 'Requested'
CANCELED = 'Canceled'
COMPLETED = 'Completed'

ORDER_STATUS = (
    (RECEIVED , 'Received'),
    (REQUESTED, 'Requested'),
    (CANCELED, 'Canceled'),
    (COMPLETED, 'Completed'),
)    

class Order(models.Model):
    orderstatus = models.OneToOneField(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class OrderStatus(models.Model):

    ORDERSTATUS = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        choices = ORDER_STATUS,
        default = RECIEVED,
    )
```

Comment: Not really sure why this is a separate model in the first place. What's the point?

Comment: I wanted to keep track of when and who made changes. I have more fields in OrderStatus. Is there any better way to manage logs of changes?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I reguraly use this pattern too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order.orderstatus` is it's own database model and `save` does not span foreign keys so you should do:

```
order.orderstatus.save()
```

instead of:

```
order.save()
```